Tkinter progress bar doesn't generate until after loop runs
I'm trying to write a GUI for a small program I wrote a while back to use with my 3D printer. I'd like for the progress bar to generate when I press OK and slowly move as each loop cycle is completed. However, the bar doesn't even generate until after the loop runs. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.
I'm also trying to get better about using comments. Please critique as needed. It'll help me learn.
""" Program to use fswebcam and user input for a controlled number of shots. """

""" Load Dependancies """
import time
import subprocess
import os    
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
""" Adds a progress bar as a visual indication of status."""
def progbar():
    bar = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='determinate')
    bar.pack()
    makercam()
"""Gets user input to set total images and countdown."""
def makercam():
    """ Set Variables """
    ehour = enthour.get()
    emin = entmin.get()
    cam_hours = int (ehour)
    cam_minutes = int (emin)
    timer = (cam_hours * 60) + cam_minutes
    img_total = timer
    img_count = 1
 
    """ Do While Loop - Calls to fswebcam config. Counts down total images with 60 seconds between."""
    while timer > 0:
        # subprocess.call(['fswebcam', '-c', '/home/user/Documents/fswebcam.conf'])
        timer -= 1
        print('Image ' + str(img_count) + ' of ' + str(img_total), end='\r')
        img_count += 1
        if timer != 0:
                    time.sleep(60)
            
        
        """ TKInter Build"""        
window=tk.Tk()
window.title("Maker Cam")
greeting = tk.Label(text="Welcome to Maker Cam!")
greeting.pack()
space = tk.Label()
space.pack()
hourgreet = tk.Label(text="Enter the run hours.")
hourgreet.pack()
enthour = tk.Entry()
enthour.pack()
mingreet = tk.Label(text="Enter the run minutes.")
mingreet.pack()
entmin = tk.Entry()
entmin.pack()
B = Button(window, text ="OK", command = progbar)
B.pack()

window.mainloop()



You are missing bar.start()

Why do you need space? Use padx and pady for hourgreet

EDIT: I can't reproduce your problem, but here is my first idea of what the solution could have been:
Tkinter doesn't update all the time. In progbar, your progress bar is generated, but the function doesn't return afterwards. Instead you wait in the makercam function.
From the docs (should apply to updating of widgets as much as for events):

Tcl/Tk applications are normally event-driven, meaning that after initialization, the interpreter runs an event loop (i.e. Tk.mainloop()) and responds to events. Because it is single-threaded, event handlers must respond quickly, otherwise they will block other events from being processed. To avoid this, any long-running computations should not run in an event handler, but are either broken into smaller pieces using timers, or run in another thread. [...]

I believe I have two solutions for your problem.

You can queue the makercam function to run separately, so tkinter can update the bar widget, by calling .after() on any widget with a delay of 1 ms.
bar.after(1, makercam)

You can force the widget to update by calling .update_idletasks (or if not working .update on bar after packing.
bar.update_idletasks()


